# Divergence: Exterior vs Covariant

Tags: differential-geometry

The divergence of a vector field can be defined as the contraction of the covariant derivative, or lowering the field into a one-form and using the Hodge star and the exterior derivative.  Are they the same? Where is it proved?

Answer (score 1):

There are three definitions about divergence.
$$divX=tr\nabla X =L_{X} *1=d \circ i_{X}(*1)=\delta X^\flat$$

For reference Riemannian Geometry GTM 171.

Comment: i.e. the answer is "yes, they're the same". Note that the second equality is not literally true - the last three quantities are actually top forms corresponding to the divergence via the hodge star; i.e. $\delta X^\flat = \star {\rm div} X$.